Fastlane uploads Metadata and Screenshots but they don't appear in App Store Connect
I'm new to fastlane and want to use it to update the localised metadata and screenshots for my mac app. Things seem to work fine, but the metadata and screenshots don't appear in App Store Connect. Existing screenshots are deleted. I'd be happy for any ideas.
This is the fastlane log:
$ fastlane mac metadata
[✔]  
[12:51:13]: fastlane detected a Gemfile in the current directory
[12:51:13]: However, it seems like you didn't use `bundle exec`
[12:51:13]: To launch fastlane faster, please use
[12:51:13]: 
[12:51:13]: $ bundle exec fastlane mac metadata
[12:51:13]: 
[12:51:13]: Get started using a Gemfile for fastlane https://docs.fastlane.tools/getting-started/ios/setup/#use-a-gemfile
[12:51:13]: Driving the lane 'mac metadata' 
[12:51:13]: ---------------------------------------
[12:51:13]: --- Step: app_store_connect_api_key ---
[12:51:13]: ---------------------------------------
[12:51:13]: ---------------------
[12:51:13]: --- Step: deliver ---
[12:51:13]: ---------------------
[12:51:13]: Successfully loaded '/Volumes/Projekte/Translate/Sources/Visual Studio/fastlane/Deliverfile' 

+----------------------------------------------------------------------+
|            Detected Values from './fastlane/Deliverfile'             |
+--------------------------------+-------------------------------------+
| app_identifier                 | xxxx.xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.xx |
| username                       | xxxxxx@xxxxxxx.xx                   |
| platform                       | osx                                 |
| verify_only                    | false                               |
| version_check_wait_retry_limit | 1                                   |
| skip_app_version_update        | true                                |
| force                          | true                                |
| sync_screenshots               | false                               |
| overwrite_screenshots          | false                               |
| skip_binary_upload             | true                                |
| submit_for_review              | false                               |
| automatic_release              | false                               |
+--------------------------------+-------------------------------------+

[12:51:13]: Creating authorization token for App Store Connect API

+----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|                          deliver 2.225.0 Summary                           |
+--------------------------------------+-------------------------------------+
| metadata_path                        | ./metadata                          |
| screenshots_path                     | ./screenshots                       |
| api_key                              | ********                            |
| run_precheck_before_submit           | false                               |
| username                             | xxxxxx@xxxxxxx.xx                   |
| app_identifier                       | xxxx.xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.xx |
| platform                             | osx                                 |
| edit_live                            | false                               |
| use_live_version                     | false                               |
| skip_binary_upload                   | true                                |
| skip_screenshots                     | false                               |
| skip_metadata                        | false                               |
| skip_app_version_update              | true                                |
| force                                | true                                |
| overwrite_screenshots                | false                               |
| screenshot_processing_timeout        | 3600                                |
| sync_screenshots                     | false                               |
| submit_for_review                    | false                               |
| verify_only                          | false                               |
| reject_if_possible                   | false                               |
| version_check_wait_retry_limit       | 1                                   |
| automatic_release                    | false                               |
| phased_release                       | false                               |
| reset_ratings                        | false                               |
| precheck_default_rule_level          | warn                                |
| ignore_language_directory_validation | false                               |
| precheck_include_in_app_purchases    | true                                |
+--------------------------------------+-------------------------------------+

[12:51:17]: No changes to localized App Info detected. Skipping upload.
[12:51:18]: Will begin uploading metadata for '0.9.1' on App Store Connect
[12:51:18]: Uploading metadata to App Store Connect for version
[12:51:25]: Will begin uploading snapshots for '0.9.1' on App Store Connect
[12:51:25]: Starting with the upload of screenshots...
[✔] Waiting for all the screenshots to finish being processed... 
[12:51:26]: Successfully uploaded all screenshots
[✔] Sorting screenshots uploaded... 
[12:51:27]: Successfully uploaded screenshots to App Store Connect

+------------------------------------------------+
|                fastlane summary                |
+------+---------------------------+-------------+
| Step | Action                    | Time (in s) |
+------+---------------------------+-------------+
| 1    | app_store_connect_api_key | 0           |
| 2    | deliver                   | 13          |
+------+---------------------------+-------------+

[12:51:27]: fastlane.tools finished successfully 

Deliverfile:
app_identifier "xxxx.xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.xx"
username "xxxxxx@xxxxxxx.xx" 

platform "osx"
verify_only false
version_check_wait_retry_limit 1
skip_app_version_update true
force true
sync_screenshots false
overwrite_screenshots true
skip_binary_upload true
submit_for_review false
automatic_release false

Fastfile:
platform :mac do
  desc "Upload metadata and screenshots"
  lane :metadata do
    api_key = app_store_connect_api_key(
      key_id: 'xxxxxxxxxx',
      issuer_id: 'xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx',
      key_filepath: '/Volumes/Daten/Zertifikate und API-Schlüssel (Apple)/App Store Connect.p8'
    )
    deliver(
      metadata_path: "./metadata",
      screenshots_path: "./screenshots",
      api_key: api_key,
      run_precheck_before_submit: false
    )
  end
end


I found the solution!
If the metadata and screenshots are located in the default folders and the paths to the default folders are set in the Fastfile like I did, the upload does not work, but Fastlane does not notice this.
